# PHP OAuth with Reddit

Tags: php, oauth

I'm trying to enable "oauth" for Reddit and I'm following the instructions given here - `https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2`

It's all good until I need to make a request for the "access_token".

The documentation says I need to make a "POST" request to the following URL

```
https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token
```

With the following as POST DATA

```
grant_type=authorization_code&code=CODE&redirect_uri=URI
```

It also says

```
You must supply your OAuth2 client's credentials via HTTP Basic Auth for this request. The "user" is the client_id, the "password" is the client_secret.
```

And I'm not sure what above means. I've tried a number of different approaches but I'm still getting 401 error. Here's my "POST" code

```
$data = array('client_id'     => self::CLIENT_ID,
              'client_secret' => self::CLIENT_SECRET,
              'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
              'code'          => $_GET['code'],
              'redirect_uri'  => $my_redirect_url);
$response = Requests::post(self::GET_OAUTH_TOKEN_URL, array(), $data);
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to additionally provide an "**Authorization**" header in this format:

"**Basic** *%base_64_encoded_string%*"

That base 64 string starts out as "username:password" or in this case "*clientid:clientsecret*", and then you encode it. So your Authorization header value would end up looking something like this:

"***Authorization: Basic d2hhdCB1cCBob21leSBn***"